# Cant access file properties!

Tags: 12.04, permissions, file-properties

I have ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin installed on my laptop. I am the admin of the computer, but anytime I try to change file permissions to acces files or tick exectute file as program then he just changes back quickly or unticks the box quickly. Please help!!!

Comment: What filesystem are the files you are trying to change on?

Comment: filesystem? Explain please...

Comment: Are the files on a flash drive or external hard drive? Did you set up partitions yourself?

Comment: They are on a partition I created earlier on windows 7.
But now i swaped from windows 7 to ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 partitions are created using the NTFS filesystem, which does not support Unix-style file permissions, which Ubuntu uses. You can, however, use Umask along with `fstab` to mount easily:

1. Run `gksu gedit /etc/fstab` to open Text Editor.
2. You are now in `fstab`.
3. Open a Terminal. Determine the partition UUID:

   ```
   blkid
   ```

and note the UUID for your partition.

1. Also make a directory to mount:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/windisk
   ```
2. Now go back to the text editor and add a line:

   ```
   UUID=[YOUR UUID HERE] /media/windisk ntfs-3g auto,users,permissions 0 0
   ```

Save, and reboot.

You can now mount this partition and work with permissions on it.

Comment: Actually, [you can make NTFS-3G respect the NTFS ownership and permissions on the drive](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/ownership-and-permissions/). (It's just a bit complicated and often not worthwhile.)